Microcontroller with battery backup: charging, charge monitoring, and low-battery power-off
I am working on a circuit that needs to interface with 12 V sensors and actuators.
The system is normally powered from 220 V AC and it has a 12 V backup lead-acid battery, so there will be some 220 V AC to 12 V DC transformer to always provide a 12 V line (which might come either from the transformer or from the battery).
While sensors and actuators work at 12 V, the actual logic will be driven by some microcontroller (operating at a lower voltage) with a 12 V-to-5 V (or 12 V-to-3.3 V) converter. I am now faced with the issue of:

Charging/Keeping the backup 12 V battery charged when the main 220A C power is available. This task in itself should be doable by some IC like the LM317.

Estimating the charge level of the battery. This task in itself could be done by measuring the output voltage of the battery (via an external ADC or using a voltage divider fed into an analog pin of the microcontroller), but I'm not sure how to combine this AND battery charging. I would also need to know if the system is currently being powered by battery, but this seems easy (by checking the “direction” of the current into the 12 V-to-5 V converter using diodes and a voltage divider so that either a logical HIGH or a logical LOW is fed into some ping of the microcontroller).

Powering everything down when there is no main power and the backup battery is critically low. The TL77xxA IC seems to do something similar, but I'm afraid that disconnecting the sensors/actuators from the battery might cause the sensed voltage to be higher, re-powering the whole circuit just for the voltage to drop down again. Perhaps something similar with hysteresis could work?


I would appreciate some guidance on how to attack this problem by someone more expert than me. It seems like my setting should be a reasonably common one, but I'm not really finding solutions that tackle all the above requirements...

Your suggested solution sounds plausible, but which cell chemistry do you want to use? Some battery types allow trickle charge, others need more design effort. The question is a bit broad to be answered just with facts.

@Jens It's a lead-acid battery.

OK, then you can use trickle charge. Draw a circuit diagram and focus to a more specific detail you are worried about.

that battery chemistry belongs in the question, edit it appropriately.
